# accepts_nested_attributes_for -- why is my form deleting instances from my nested model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-attributes

I have...

**/app/models/survey.rb**:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :results
  belongs_to :competitor
  after_commit :create_matching_results  
  attr_accessible :results_attributes
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :results
  after_commit :create_matching_results
  def create_matching_results
    unless self.destroyed?
      self.fields.each do |field|
        result = survey.results.find_or_create_by_survey_id_and_field_id(self.id, field_id)
        result.update_attributes :competitor_id => competitor.id
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**/app/models/result.rb**:

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :field_id, :survey_id, :competitor_id, :value, :selected, :name
  belongs_to :survey
end
```

**/app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb**:

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController  
  def edit
    @competitor = Competitor.find(params[:competitor_id])
    @survey = @competitor.surveys.find(params[:id])
  end
  def update
    @competitor = Competitor.find(params[:competitor_id])
    @survey = @competitor.surveys.find(params[:id])
    @result_ids = params[:survey]["result_ids"]
    @survey.results.each do |result|
      result.update_attributes :selected => true if result.id == @result_ids.to_i
      result.update_attributes :selected => false unless result.id == @result_ids.to_i
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Survey was successfully updated. (#{undo_link(@survey)}.)" if @survey.update_attributes(params[:survey])
    respond_with(@competitor, @survey)
  end
end
```

**/app/views/surveys/_form.html.haml**:

```
= simple_form_for [@competitor, @survey] do |f|
  = f.collection_radio_buttons :result_ids, @survey.results, :id, :name
  = f.button :submit, :id => 'submit_survey'
```

Now let's assume that @survey.results.count == 2. Then, I'll get some lovely HTML like this in my form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/competitors/13/surveys/80" class="simple_form edit_survey" id="edit_survey_80" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">
  <input id="survey_result_ids_673" name="survey[result_ids]" type="radio" value="673" />
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="survey_result_ids_673">one</label>
  <input id="survey_result_ids_672" name="survey[result_ids]" type="radio" value="672" />
  <label class="collection_radio_buttons" for="survey_result_ids_672">two</label>
  <input class="btn" id="submit_survey" name="commit" type="submit" value="Update Survey" />
</form>
```

So far, so good.

When I select one of these two radio buttons, my params look like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"etc...",
 "survey"=>{"result_ids"=>"672"},
 "commit"=>"Update Survey",
 "action"=>"update",
 "controller"=>"surveys",
 "competitor_id"=>"13",
 "id"=>"80"}
```

As a result, I expect the `selected` value of `Result.find(672)` to be set to `true` and the `selected` value of the other result to be set to `false`. Instead, I'm finding that the other result is being deleted altogether. What's going on? And how can I fix it?

**UPDATE**:

For example, I start with `@survey.results.count == 4`, with a `results.selected == false`. Then I do the following in Rspec:

```
visit edit_competitor_survey_path(@competitor, @survey)
  choose "Standard practice"
  @dummy = @survey.results.map{|result| [result.name, " - ", result.selected].join}
  click_on "submit_survey"
  @survey.results.reload.map{|result| [result.name, " - ", result.selected].join}.should == @dummy
```

I then get:

```
Failure/Error: @survey.results.reload.map{|result| [result.name, " ", result.selected].join}.should == @dummy
       expected: ["Best practice - false", "Good practice - false", "Standard practice - false", "Bad practice - false"]
            got: ["Standard practice - true"] (using ==)
```

(Not that I expect the 'before' and 'after' values to be equal. This trick is just a handy way of showing both values in an Rspec test failure message.)

Answer (score 0):

Answer was to remove `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as I was already setting my results values directly.

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :competitor
  attr_accessible :selection
  attr_accessor :selection
  has_many :results
  belongs_to :question
end

class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  def update
    @competitor = Competitor.find(params[:competitor_id])
    @survey = @competitor.surveys.find(params[:id])
    @result_ids = params[:survey]["selection"]
    @survey.results.each do |result|
      result.update_attributes :selected => true if result.id == @result_ids.to_i
      result.update_attributes :selected => false unless result.id == @result_ids.to_i
    end
    flash[:notice] = "Survey was successfully updated. (#{undo_link(@survey)}.)" if @survey.update_attributes(params[:survey])
    respond_with(@competitor, @survey)
  end  
end

= simple_form_for [@competitor, @survey] do |f|
  = f.collection_radio_buttons :selection, @survey.results, :id, :name
  = f.button :submit, :id => 'submit_survey'
```